# Django App not showing in admin after installing django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.9

After installing django 1.9 I'm having problems trying to show my apps in the Admin interface, this is my code:

app name: people

```
#models.py:

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
#admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

admin.register(Person)
```

```
#apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PeopleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'people'
```

```
#settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'people'
]
```

I changed the last line of INSTALLED_APPS to 'people.apps.PeopleConfig' without success. Python version 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem

```
#Change:
admin.register(Person)
#To this:
admin.site.register(Person)
```

Sorry.